# Latex: Can I cite a reference after the bibliography

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex, biblatex

I'm having trouble with citations after the bibliography (in my appendices) using Bibtex/pdflatex.  I'm using the 'puthesis' class - Purdue's class for our theses - which is built on top of the 'report' class.  I'm using package 'natbib' with the option 'numbers'.  An MWE isn't really feasible, but an example is shown below

```
\documentclass[english, ne, thesis]{puthesis}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
\chapter{Body Chapter}
Citations work fine here \cite{abc123}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{dissertation.bib}
\appendices
\chapter{Appendix Chapter}
Citations don't work here, I get an error that the 
"Package natbib Warning: Citation `Crane1991' on page 145 undefined
on input line 4940." \cite{abc1234}
\end{document}
```

Some obvious things:

- The citation does exist in the .bib file.
- I'm running `pdflatex; bibtex; pdflatex; pdflatex`
- I get the same error with and without the `\appendices` line.

Is there a way to cite references in latex **after** the bibliography?

Comment: A minimal working example is *always* feasible. See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/5764)

Comment: @Werner a MWE for this problem would involve me distributing the .cls file for Purdue’s thesis, which I’m not entirely sure I am allowed to do. There are additionally several .sty files that must be distributed, too. And at least 100 lines of boilerplate to make the thesis compile. A MWE is not feasible in this case. Thanks for your helpful replay.

Comment: ...in order to help you, you need to help the community. Provide links to these files so that your problem can be reproduced. If we can't reproduce it, it's probably not going to be solved. From what I see in your current code and description, there shouldn't be a problem. `\cite`s (like `\label`s and `\ref`s) can be anywhere; before/after their use/definition.

Comment: Is this the class file: [`puthesis.cls`](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/supported/puthesis.cls)? Nothing in the file or [additional information page](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/) provides anything regarding copyright. So I don't see any issue with providing the appropriate links in your question, a single, working bibliography item using [`filecontents`](//ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) so that the file can compile and replicate the problem. "100 lines of boilerplate [stuff]" that makes the file compile seems strange...

Comment: @Werner Thanks for looking into this so closely. I'm attempting to generate an MWE, but I can't replicate the behavior. It's still happening in my dissertation, of course.  I think it may be a waste of your time to continue looking into it until I can track down what's actually causing the citation problems, but I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by a non-UTF8/Latin9 encoded character in my .bib file.  After ensuring the correct encoding with

```
recode utf8..l9 dissertation.bib
```

the file compiled as expected.